# node find fs.existsSync is not a function

Tags: node.js, angular

I'm trying to read in a list of files contained in a directory using nodejs 'find' (https://www.npmjs.com/package/find) in an angular-cli app and getting this error

```
'ERROR TypeError: fs.existsSync is not a function'.
```

There are a lot of posts regarding this error and all seem to reference the use of require('fs') vs. 'find'. I have the code below within a service.

```
let find = require('find');
    find.file('../assets/img/', function(files) {
      console.log(files.length);
    });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This might be relevent: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/7596

Comment: Yeah, I saw this. Except there's no import of HttpClient in the app. Here's my code (https://github.com/itLead797/ImageGallery)

Comment: Is it possible HttpClient is being imported without the existence of an import statement in the app?